# how to download attachments from multiple emails on a specific range date and specific subject using Perl?

Tags: perl, imap

I need to download attachments from multiple emails on a specific range date and specific subject.

In specific range date, i.e. 01/10/2016 to 02/02/2017 and subject "Cambridge".

I use imap gmail account. How do I do it using Perl?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: That seems awfully broad. Do you have a specific problem you're struggling with?

Comment: Since stackoverflow.com is no code writing service I only give you an overview how to do it: You can use for example [Net::IMAP::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Client) to access IMAP accounts. This provides a `search` method so you can get a listing of the specific mails. Using `fetch` you then can get the relevant mails and then use for example [MIME::Tools](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Tools) to extract the attachment from the mails.

Comment: We don't take programming assignments here and your question is very likely to be closed. Please [*take the tour*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read and absorb [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will need to put in some effort and create something that we can help you with before you get any good answers.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to download attachments from multiple emails on a specific range date and specific subject.
>
> In specific range date, i.e. 01/10/2016 to 02/02/2017 and subject "Cambridge".
>
> I use imap gmail account. How do I do it using Perl?

You will need to

- Connect to Google's IMAP server using the correct credentials
- Select the appropriate mail folder
- Search for emails that match the date and subject line criteria
- For each mail found, fetch the required attachment

Comment: The last 2 steps: i could only search by subject, but not both by date and subject using Mail::IMAPClient

Comment: @Amedxy: We can't help you fix your code without seeing it.